# jquery issues with variables/pageYOffset

Tags: jquery

My javascript is having issues with the variable posy. This is all within a jquery onload function. Can anyone help me understand what is not right about this line?

```
var dhei = $('.share_event_btn').offset();

var posy = (dhei.top+22)-(self.pageYOffset);
```

EDIT:

```
var ehei = $('.share_event_btn').offset();
var dhei = parseInt(ehei);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the issue?

Comment: The issue was merely that one of these lines stopped all my javascript working. Me be stupid - sorry guys. The jquery method returns an object not an INT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
self.pageYOffset
```

Try:

```
window.pageYOffset
```

**Note:**

`pageYOffset` is not a reserved word so you can declare your own variable or function called pageYOffset but if you do then you will not be able to find or alter the scroll position of a window in some browsers